# uWSGI Server log…permission denied to read file...which file?

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a server running Django/Nginx/uWSGI with uWSGI in emperor mode, and the error log for it (the vassal-level error log, not the emperor-level log) has a continual permissions error every time it spawns a new worker, like so:

> Tue Jun 26 19:34:55 2012 - Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 9334)
>
> Error opening file for reading: Permission denied

Problem is, I don't know what file it's having trouble opening; it's not the log file, obviously, since I'm looking at it and it's writing to that without issue. Any way to find out? I'm running the apt-get version of uWSGI 1.0.3-debian through Upstart on Ubuntu 12.04. The site is working successfully, aside from what seems like a memory leak...hence my looking at the log file. I've experimented with changing the permissions of the entire /opt/ directory to include the uwsgiuser user, to no avail. I'm using a TCP socket, so permissions shouldn't be an issue there. Is it the cache? Does that have its' own permissions? If so, where?

```
My Upstart conf file

description "uWSGI" start on runlevel [2345] stop on runlevel [06] respawn

env UWSGI=/usr/bin/uwsgi env LOGTO=/var/log/uwsgi/emperor.log

exec $UWSGI \
--master \
--emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals \
--die-on-term \
--auto-procname \
--no-orphans \
--logto $LOGTO \
--logdate
```

My Vassal ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
# Variables
base = /opt/env/mysiteenv

# Generic Config
uid = uwsgiuser
gid = uwsgiuser
socket = 127.0.0.1:5050
master = true
processes = 2
reload-on-as = 128
harakiri = 60
harakiri-verbose = true
auto-procname = true
plugins = http,python
cache = 2000
home = %(base)
pythonpath = %(base)/mysite
module = wsgi
logto = /opt/log/mysite/error.log
logdate = true
```

Comment: This is probably more likely to get a useful answer on ServerFault.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The actual answer to this question appears to be this Ubuntu-specific bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libjpeg-turbo/+bug/1031718

You can work around the problem by putting the lines

```
setuid uwsgiuser
setgid uwsgiuser
```

into your upstart configuration file, and deleting the `uid` and `gid` settings from your uwsgi configuration.

Comment: This totally worked; thank you so much. The error had been driving me crazy.

Comment: What is upstart configuration file?

Comment: @uszywieloryba [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com) is Ubuntu’s init replacement.  It runs jobs based on files in `/etc/init` (amongst other places).

Answer (score 3):

You could try to `strace` the process and see what triggers the error message, something like:

`UWSGI=/usr/bin/uwsgi LOGTO=/var/log/uwsgi/emperor.log strace -f -o strace.log -etrace=open,write $UWSGI
--master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --die-on-term --auto-procname --no-orphans --logto $LOGTO --logdate`