# uWSGI error: "Error opening file for reading: Permission denied'

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I am experiencing the exact same error described here:

[uWSGI Server log…permission denied to read file...which file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220355/uwsgi-server-logpermission-denied-to-read-file-which-file)

uWSGI keeps throwing me "Error opening file for reading: Permission denied" in the logs.

However I am starting uWSGI with a traditional init.d script. As such, the fix described in the above article does not apply to me. Can anyone assist me with resolving this issue? I believe it is related to this bug (as mentioned in the above link): 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libjpeg-turbo/+bug/1031718

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user that's running the uWSGI process has read permissions on the file it needs to read. You can easily see the user that's running uwsgi by grepping on `ps`:

```
ps aux | grep uwsgi
```

in the first column you'll see the user that's running the command in the rightmost column.

Comment: The problem is `/proc/self/auxv`, and it's being read by `libjpeg-turbo8`.  It's an Ubuntu specific problem, caused by the fact that `/proc/self/auxv` is owned by the user that started the process, which if you change uid means you can't read it any more.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is essentially the same, and it's caused by the same issue.  You cannot use the `uid` and `gid` options in the uWSGI configuration file, because doing so prevents the process from reading `/proc/self/auxv`, which causes the messages you’re seeing.

One way to solve the problem would be to use sudo to invoke uwsgi, e.g.

```
sudo -u uwsgiuser -g uwsgiuser /path/to/uwsgi
```

rather than executing it directly.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. @alastair Since I am not running uWSGI with an upstart, how can I implement the same setuid/setgid fix?   When I issue the sudo command you mention, I get the following response:    open("/var/log/uwsgi/app/baruwa.log"): Permission denied [utils.c line 246]

Comment: Please read the error message!  It tells you what the problem is (you don't have permission to create that log file).  You need to fix the permissions so that you do, or you need to change the path to somewhere you *can* write to.

Comment: It appears that invoking uwsgi as any user other than `root` involves some fairly deep configuration changes (deeper than just permissions).  I believe the whole startup script needs to be modified as it creates/removes directories.  Would you have any other suggests on how I should resolve this?  I can post my startup script if you think that will help.  At the end of all my permission modifications I end up with: `failjob-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory`

Comment: At this point I think, if you need this urgently, it would be a good idea to hire an experienced UNIX sysadmin to help you.  Another option you might consider is using a different WSGI host; [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org) is quite good.