# uwsgi Error opening file for reading: Permission denied

Tags: python, uwsgi

I have got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220355/uwsgi-server-log-permission-denied-to-read-file-which-file) problem.
Didn't understand how to fix it. 
How to set setguid for uwsgi on Ubuntu ?

Comment: Is there something specific that makes you think it's a `sticky-bit` problem, rather than a more typical owner/group permissioning problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the owners and permissions on the files that it is trying to access.

1. what user:group is uwsgi running as?
2. what user:group are the files it is trying to access?

You can set the former in the uwsgi config ini via:

```
uid = john
gid = www-data
```

And you can check the latter with `ls -al` eg:

```
Johns-iMac:latest johnmee$ ls -al
total 96
-rw-r--r--   1 johnmee  staff  2316 13 Oct 10:15 blog.py
drwxr-xr-x  46 johnmee  staff  1564 29 May  2011 meejinnz
drwxr-xr-x  15 johnmee  staff   510 14 Oct 15:29 pages
-rw-r--r--   1 johnmee  staff    11  6 Oct 10:35 settings.ini
drwxr-xr-x   6 johnmee  staff   204  7 Oct 19:20 static
drwxr-xr-x   7 johnmee  staff   238 13 Oct 18:08 templates
```

As laid out the above may not work because uwsgi is running as `john:www-data` whereas the files are `johnmee:staff`.  If I were having trouble getting this to work I'd start by putting the files in the same group as the process and setting read permissions appropriately.

Ultimately you'll find the best answers in the log files; perhaps located someplace like `/var/log/uwsgi/app/john.log`.  Take care because the responses can change subtly: all the errors look very similar so you can change one thing for the better but not notice the error message has progressed to something else.